# Why is New York called 紐約?

Tags: etymology, place-names

New York (state and city) is called 紐約 (Niǔ​yuē).

**Of course that sounds very much like the English "New York", but how come it's written with 紐 and 約?**

When I look up the characters I get:

紐 knot; button; handle, knob; tie

約 treaty, agreement, covenant

---

Does the meaning of the characters have anything to do with them being used in this word, or is it simply that they sound similar to the English -- if so, why where these particular characters chosen to begin with and not some other characters that sound the same?

Comment: cf. 纽芬兰岛  Newfoundland, 纽伦堡 Nuremberg，纽马克特 Newmarket，of course "New"  in names is also often transliterated as 新 （as in New Delhi, Nova Scotia, New Caledonia),約: 約克  York, 約克郡 Yorkshire,

Comment: Sometimes a phonetic transcription is just a phonetic transcription. _Usually_ it is.

Comment: another example of `New` phonetically transcripted as `紐`: New Zeland = 紐西蘭

Comment: note 约克 for   Toronto suburb "York" s.http://www.rfa.org/mandarin/yataibaodao/junshiwaijiao/zw-02032017130922.html

Comment: New Zealand: Wiki, baike:新西兰 (baike: 又译纽西兰) 新泽西州 New Jersey, 新南威尔士州 New South Wales, 新地岛 Novaya Zemlya 新墨西哥州 New Mexico, 新西伯利亚Novosibirsk,新奥尔良 New Orleans,新布朗斯维克 New Brunswick USA,(s.c. #1 新德里 New Delhi, 新斯科舍省 Nova Scotia,新喀里多尼亚 New Caledonia)

phonetic:下诺夫哥罗德 Nizhny Novgorod,諾伊豪森 Neuhausen,纳沙泰尔Neuchâtel,纽宾士域省 New Brunswick (province,Ca),baike:别 名:新不伦瑞克省,New Brunswick University 纽宾士域大学,
 **纳吾肉孜节**   也译诺鲁兹节或耨儒孜节 Nowruz (New Year) festival (Persian,literally "New Day")

Comment: For preferred transliteration of New Zealand note  新西兰驻华大使馆   Embassy of New Zealand in China http://www.kanguowai.com/site/2153.html

Answer (score 7):

紐約 in Cantonese is nau2 joek3 (j- in jyutping is pronounced like y-). That's the closest Cantonese immigrants could come to New York, I suppose...

There aren't many syllabes in Cantonese that could match York:

- jaak [ja:k]
- jik
- joek [jøk]
- juk [jok] --> that last one could have been a better match.

Comment: So did this word originate from Cantonese and later imported into Mandarin/Putonghua?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, the pronunciation was based on Cantonese instead of modern Mandarin. (E.g.  "Taxi" is translated as  "的士" in Cantonese but it's also acceptable in Mandarin that sounds very differently)    [Ref:Taxi in Wikipeidia](https://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9A%84%E5%A3%AB). I'm thinking it might also apply to 紐約 original sound

Comment: 纽约： jyutping    nau2 joek3

Answer (score 3):

There are three universal rules for name translation in Mandarin:

> 信 ：precision
>
> 达 : meaningful
>
> 雅 : elegant

For places historical naming is used. But if there is no precedent name, phonetic name is used, which then has to be chosen so it is made up of elegant characters.

The closest phonetic sound for `New` is `妞`， `York` sound `哟`. Both does not follow the elegant rules. Then the next selection will be `牛， 纽， 纽`.

Because New York is a commercial hub, the term **`枢纽`** come into mind. And using `约` is quite obvious， as in `条约`。

Thus，`纽约` are meaningful and elegant.

Comment: Hi, **1**) would be nice with a ref to more about the "three rules". **2**) In which way is 妞 and 哟 not elegant? You mean that the characters are comparatively cluttered?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be well supported, given the facts in the other answers. If it were being transcribed into Mandarin today, it probably would account for the final "k" sound. The evidence seems to suggest it *does* account for the final "k" sound, but only in Cantonese. No need to explain further than that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is in reference to the purchase of Manhattan from the Native Americans by the Dutch for $24 worth of beads.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that 紐 is used for "New" in so many place name and the fact that it is the Chinese equivalent of the Greek letter *Nu*  suggests that there is a *de facto* system; of course we can't rule out the involvement of a committee at some point.